# VSE. Textures missing when combining video clips with 3D scene

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, scene

In addition to a few video clips I have added a scene with a 3D model to my video sequence editor. Now the final render of the video does not appear to have rendered several settings that I have given the objects in that scene such as the materials for instance. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Objects don't render if there's a video on the VSE.

Comment: Is there a way around that?

Comment: @NewToBlender on the viewer press "n", on the right tab look for the scene preview/render uncheck OpenGl and set the render level to Rendered http://i.stack.imgur.com/ma7oU.png

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't see a change. To be clear it's not just the preview that's missing things but the final rendered video.

Comment: Can you post images showing how you have your elements organized?

Comment: It's okay. I can just render out the scene as a sequence of png images and insert those into the sequence editor. It's more cumbersome and means that not everything is contained in a single file but it works.